# Fill parent variable when calling an abstract method in child

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I have two classes:

```
public abstract class Parent{
   Object parentObj;
   public abstract Object something();

}
```

And

```
public class Child extends Parent{

  @Override 
  public Object something(){
     return new Object();
  }

}
```

Is there any way to do something in the parent to set `parentObj` every time the `something()` method is called?

I don't want to set `parentObj` in every child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
public abstract class Parent{
    Object parentObj;

    public final Object something() {
        parentObj = ...;
        return doSomething();
    }

    protected abstract Object doSomething();

}
```

and

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    @override 
    protected Object doSomething(){
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

That's called the template method pattern.

Comment: Can be difficult to do this if this is part of a public API where the override is already being called directly by consumers though (don't know if that's an issue based on the context) - you'd have to be able to rename all of the overrides which may not be possible if consumers are providing their own extensions.

Comment: Yep - that's what I'm getting at. Again, may not be an issue; depends on the wider context of the question.